# Is there a more efficient way of adding and removing these CSS classes with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below script that uses [slidebars](https://www.adchsm.com/slidebars/) to show and hide a side menu.

I need to add and remove a CSS class to another div to tie things together. But looking at the way I am adding and removing classes I feel like there's a more efficient way?

```
function slidebarsStatus() {

  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  breakpoint = 992; 

  if ( windowWidth > breakpoint ) {

    controller.open( 'site-menu' ); 
    $('.site-wrap').addClass('menu-active');


  }

  else {

    controller.close( 'site-menu' );
    $('.site-wrap').removeClass('menu-active');
    $('.site-wrap').addClass('menu-inactive');



  }

}

slidebarsStatus();
$(window).on( 'resize', slidebarsStatus );
```

Comment: It may be more effective to use media queries in css.

Comment: You shouldn't have to add one class and remove another. The presence/absence of a single class should be enough.

Comment: It is not immediately obvious what you are trying to do, but an alternative using JavaScript would be to wrap the open/close methods of slidebars with your own functions that are responsible for adding or removing the classes too. But if your classes are toggles only based on the viewport width, then definitely media queries are the ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Store the jQuery object as a variable:

```
var siteWrap = $('.site-wrap');
```

And chain your methods to the variable:

```
siteWrap.removeClass('menu-active').addClass('menu-inactive');
```

Or, if possible, media queries in your CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .site-wrap {
        /* active appearance */
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .site-wrap {
        /* inactive appearance */
    }
}
```